# How can I get just the value of a Choice column in PowerApps and convert it into JSON from SharePoint List?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Getting just the column value

I have a 2 columns of DataType Choice and Person in my SharePoint List, I'm trying to convert it into JSON but these columns are showing as

`{Choice_Column: {Value: Actual_Value}}`

The way I'm getting the data is

`ShowColumns(Filter(), "Choice_Column", "Person_Column")`

Can someone help me how I can just get the value and have the output as shown below?

`{Choice_Column: Actual_Value}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ForAll function to "shape" the result as you want:

```
ForAll(
  Filter(...),
  {
    Choice_Column: Choice_Column.Value,
    Person_Column: Person_Column.DisplayName
  }
)
```

If you have many other columns that you need, you can use the AddColumns to add  new columns with the values extracted:

```
AddColumns(
  Filter(...),
  "Choice", Choice_Column.Value,
  "Person", Person_Column.DisplayName
)
```

You can also use the DropColumns to remove the original columns if you need:

```
DropColumns(
  AddColumns(
    Filter(...),
    "Choice", Choice_Column.Value,
    "Person", Person_Column.DisplayName
  ),
  "Choice_Column", "Person_Column"
)
```